# Customizing plone login for two factor authentication

Tags: python, authentication, plone, zope, two-factor-authentication

I am new to plone and python.
But here comes a scenario where i want to customize an existing plone installation login to include two factor auth from [Duo-Security](http://www.duosecurity.com/).
What is the easiest way to accomplish this ?
For this requirement,what are the areas i need to explore ?
If anyone has done this before,please give me some pointers.

Comment: Is there a Python API for http://www.duosecurity.com/? If so, then a PAS plugin should be easy-ish.

Comment: There is a Python implementation from duo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication in Plone is very flexible and modular. After a short search I found out that there not a product that already provides this kind of auth, so you need to write a custom PAS (Pluggable Authentication Service) plugin.

More info:

- http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/users-and-security/pluggable-authentication-service
- http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/appendix-practicals/b-org-creating-content-types-the-plone-2.5-way/writing-a-custom-pas-plug-in

Answer (score 1):

See PlonePAS.

Additionally, see the following packages as an example.

- https://github.com/collective/collective.googleauthenticator
- https://github.com/collective/collective.smsauthenticator